# Calculate integer summation when lower bound is a variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, computer-science

How do you calculate the following sum?

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=k}^n i
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_{i=k}^n i = \sum_{i=0}^n i - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} i = \frac{1}{2} \left[ n(n+1)  - (k-1)k \right]$

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case for the formula for the sum of n terms in an arithmetic progression:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have specified that I was looking for a direct formula or derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I was able to find it here, thanks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Some_summations_of_polynomial_expressions